# Virturalbox accelerate guest clock not effective on some OS

Tags: virtual-machine, clock

I am trying to increase the clock rate of a guest operating system, such that as 1 second pass by in the host machine, 2 seconds pass by in the guest OS. I am following [this documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#warpguest), by running

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage" 200
```

However, it seems that the guest OS are running faster (e.g. it takes less time to boot the OS), but on some systems the date and time is still passing by in normal rate.

To be specific, I have a Debian 9 virtual machine with no graphical interface and a Windows XP. For Windows XP, if I open the clock, I can see that every second it ticks about twice. However, on Debian, if I run `watch -n 0 date`, the time ticks once per second.

So why is this happening? Did I get confused on the definition of clock? (e.g. CPU clock and clock that keeps track of date and time?) Or is there still some way that Debian can use to access the clock in the host machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Try to set the "Paravirtualization Interface" to "Legacy" in the Settings>System>Acceleration.

Comment: Though not fully tested, it seems that setting that to "Legacy" makes the clock in my Debian 9 virtual machine tick faster, which solves my problem.